# Template nordemailer with twig

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, twig

I want to template an email with nodemailer and twig. How can I do it?

My code:

```
var messages = {
    from: "XX",
    to: "XX",
    subject: objet,
    text: Twig.renderFile('mail.twig',{message: mess}),
    attachments:[
        {
            filename: url_facture.facture_id + '.pdf',
            content: resultat
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [Twig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twig) documentation, it seems that the renderFile method is async and require a callback.

There are several approaches to handle async functions. The fastest thing you could do is:

```
Twig.renderFile('mail.twig', {message: mess}, function(err, html){
    var messages = {
        from: "XX",
        to: "XX",
        subject: objet,
        text: html,
        attachments:[
            {
                filename: url_facture.facture_id + '.pdf',
                content: resultat
            }
        ]
    };
})
```

You can also consider using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in combination with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) commands.

Comment: Oh, I did not think about that. Thank you, I will test that tomorrow